# Como encontrar un string dentro de una lista

Tags: java, arraylist, lista

En este código , lo que necesito es comparar el string película al atributo de todos los objetos de la clase Película , y si lo encuentra retornar un booleano , pero de alguna forma no lo hace, pueden ayudarme y ver que esta mal ?.

Gracias

```
   public class Pelicula{

        private String pelicula;

        public Pelicula(int idPelicula, String pelicula) throws Exception{
            super();
            this.idPelicula = idPelicula;
            this.setPelicula(pelicula);
        }

        public void setPelicula(String pelicula) throws Exception 
        {
            boolean verificar = verificarPelicula(pelicula);
            if (verificar == false) throw new Exception("Error: Pelicula existente");
            this.pelicula=pelicula;
        }

        public boolean verificarPelicula(String pelicula)
        {
            List<Pelicula> listado = new ArrayList<>(); //intente con new ArrayList<Pelicula>

            for(int cantPel = 0 ; cantPel <listado.size();cantPel++)
           {
                if (pelicula.equals(listado.get(cantPel).pelicula))//tambien intente con .getPelicula()
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }

            public String getPelicula(){
              return pelicula;
            }
    }
```

Comment: pero listado esta vacio..

Comment: Como comenta gbianchi tu List es vacio por lo tanto no entraría ni al for para realizar la comparación por esta razón simpre obtendras el valor true.

Answer (score 2):

Deberias tener otra clase que guarde tus peliculas o en la misma clase poner lista de peliculas. En fin vos decidis como hacer, pero para buscar una pelicula podes hacer asi:

```
    list<Pelicula> peliculas

    public boolean verificarPelicula(String peliculaBuscada) {
        peliculas.stream().anyMatch(pelicula -> pelicula.getPelicula() == peliculaBuscada);
    }
```

Te explico el código. Tenemos una lista de peliculas y utilizo el método stream(), con esto podemos usar lambda, si no sabes que es, te recomiendo investigar porque soluciona muchas cosas y esta muy bueno para usar. Luego uso el método anyMatch, que basicamente lo que hace es devolver un booleano del bloque que se especifica en anyMatch, y dentro del anyMatch utilizas un parametro cualquiera (en este caso puse pelicula, pero puede ser x, y) y si te das cuenta en el parametro podes usar los metodos de pelicula y lo último que haces es buscar la pelicula que queres. 
El stream().anyMatch() seria algo parecido con un for:

```
    public boolean verificarPelicula(String peliculaBuscada) {
            boolean existe = false;
            for(Pelicula pelicula : peliculas) {
                    if(pelicula.getPelicula() == peliculaBuscada)
                            existe = true;
            }
            return existe;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes un problema con tu diseño, tu clase hace mucho, ella no debería revisar por si misma si contiene más películas.

Lo que te recomiendo es que sobreescribas el método `hashCode` y `equals` de la clase película utilizando solo tu atributo película.

así podrás obtener desde la colección `listado.contains()` si existe.;

Comment: por lo que dice OP, creo que sobreescribir metodos es demasiado complejo...

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo quieres tener como un cojunto de peliculas, e ir agregando peliculas a este conjunto sin tener peliculas con id duplicados, en ese caso tendria dos clases, la clase `Pelicula` que tendria el id de la pelicula y el texto, y el cojunto `Shelf`, donde iria agrupando las peliculas.

El problema con el codigo es que intentas hacer estos pasos en una sola clase y en `List<Pelicula> listado = new ArrayList<>();` generas un cojunto de peliculas vacia cada vez que quieres verificar si una pelicula nueva es unica

Un ejemplo en java:

```
    public class Movie {
        private String title;
        private int id;
        public Movie(int id, String title) {
            this.title = title;
            this.id = id;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    };

    public class Shelf {
        private List<Movie> arr;
        private boolean alreadyExist(Movie movie) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                if (arr[i].getId() == movie.getId()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
            if (!alreadyExist(movie)) {
                // add movie to arr
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: habria que explicarle a OP que es shelf. no parece ser tan avanzado

Comment: entiendo lo que suicidio , ahora el problema es , como tendría que hacer? , estuve buscando por varios lados y no encuentro la solución. se agradece la ayuda :)

Comment: te vale una solucion en C++?

Comment: es muy linda la solucion en c++, pero OP quiere saber en java.. y esto no responde la pregunta..

Comment: updatee la solucion a java

Answer (score 0):

**Estas comparando con un listado de objetos `Pelicula` que no contiene elementos**, creas `listado` pero no contiene elementos, incluso no entra al `for` por  esta situación ya que `listado.size()` tiene valor de 0:

```
public boolean verificarPelicula(String pelicula)
{
    List<Pelicula> listado = new ArrayList<>(); //intente con new ArrayList<Pelicula>

    for(int cantPel = 0 ; cantPel <listado.size();cantPel++)
   {
        if (pelicula.equals(listado.get(cantPel).getPelicula())){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

No se realiza la comparación, por esta razón siempre obtendrás el valor `true`.

---

Como sugerencia podrías modificar tu método para que reciba el listado de Objetos y realice la comprobación deseada:

```
  public boolean verificarPelicula(String pelicula, List<Pelicula> listado)
        {    
            for(int cantPel = 0 ; cantPel <listado.size();cantPel++)
           {
                if (pelicula.equals(listado.get(cantPel).pelicula))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Cuando haces esto tu listado está vacío

```
List<Pelicula> listado = new ArrayList<>(); //intente con new ArrayList<Pelicula>
```

Como se indica en los comentarios, como el `List` está vacío no se entraría al `for` para realizar la comparación y por esta razón siempre obtendrás el valor `true`.